# Cannot read property 'keyboard' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am receiving this error `'Cannot read property 'keyboard' of undefined'` and I am unsure on what I need to do to resolve it. I am just trying to see if the keyboard appears visible on screen but this line of code  is where the error is triggered

```
wait t.expect(this.searchKeyboard.keyboard.visible).ok({ timeout: 3000 });
```

Code:

```
class SearchPage extends BasePage {
  searchKeyboard: SearchKeyboardModel;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  async enterSearchKeyword(keyword: string) {
    await t.expect(this.searchKeyboard.keyboard.visible).ok({ timeout: 3000 });
  }
}
```

...

```
export class SearchKeyboardModel {
  keyboard: Selector;

  constructor() {
    this.keyboard = getByTestId('qa-keypad-wrapper');
  }

...
```

Comment: The says it can't read `keyboard` of `undefined`. The only place you try to read `keyboard` is `this.searchKeyboard.keyboard`. I see you initialising `searchKeyboard: SearchKeyboardModel;`, but I don't see you ever assigning a value to it. Why do you expect it to be anything other than `undefined`?

Comment: @Quentin It's probably my lack of understanding on how this logic works. I thought if I access the modal then the selector within that modal that it would know what the selector is

Comment: That makes even less sense. `this` is a `SearchPage`. `this.searchKeyboard` is `undefined` (and the property is set up to a `SearchKeyboardModel` through which you access a `Selector`, not the other way around). **Why do you think that `this.searchKeyboard`should be anything other than `undeinfed`**? (Since you do nothing to assign a value to it.)

Comment: @Quentin Sorry I don't really consider myself a programmer so this is a bit more technical than my expertise. I'm actually a tester who does some automation but that's it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax:

> ```
> class SearchPage extends BasePage {
>   searchKeyboard: SearchKeyboardModel;
> ```

defines a property on instances of the class called `searchKeyboard` and states that the only kind of value you can assign to it is a value with the type "`SearchKeyboardModel`".

It does not assign a value to it though, so its initial value is `undefined`.

---

When you try to access it later:

> ```
> this.searchKeyboard.keyboard.visible
> ```

`this.searchKeyboard` is **still** `undefined` (hence the error message telling you that you are trying to read `keyboard` from `undefined`).

---

You need, at some point before you try to read the value, to *assign a value* to it.

You might do this inline if you want the value to be shared between all instances of the class:

```js
class SearchPage extends BasePage {
  searchKeyboard: SearchKeyboardModel = new SearchKeyboardModel();
```

You might do this in the constructor if each instance needs a unique value:

```js
class SearchPage extends BasePage {
  searchKeyboard: SearchKeyboardModel;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.searchKeyboard = new SearchKeyboardModel();
  }
```

---

**NB**: I have no idea what `SearchKeyboardModel` is. I don't know if that is the correct way to initialise an instance of it.